# Type error on my fit function using gaussian process in scikit

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn, interpolation

Ok, so I have been working on some code that takes an image that represents sparse point data from Houdini and interpolates it into a usable complete map.  This has been working really well, except that now I am running into some memory issues.  I have narrowed down the memory problem in the kriging algorithm I am using to the predict() step.  I am trying to use the batch_size parameter to limit the memory consumption, but it is being a pain.  I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\mapInterpolation.py", line 88, in <module>
    prepareImage(file, interpType="kriging")
  File "e:\mapInterpolation.py", line 61, in prepareImage
    rInterpInt = kriging(r).astype(int)
  File "e:\mapInterpolation.py", line 36, in kriging
    interpolated = gp.predict(rr_cc_as_cols, batch_size=a).reshape(data.shape)
  File "e:\miniconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\gaussian_process\gaussian_process
.py", line 522, in predict
    for k in range(max(1, n_eval / batch_size)):
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

I have triple checked the type that I am passing to the batch_size parameter, and it is an int, not a float.  I really need this to work so I can get an output to use in my final project for my Master's degree that is due in a few weeks.  I am including the code below.  Also, if anyone has any suggestions on how to make the radial calculation more memory efficient, I am more than open.

```
import numpy as np
def parseToM(array):
    print("parsing to matrix")
    r = np.linspace(0, 1, array.shape[0]) 
    c = np.linspace(0, 1, array.shape[1])    
    rr, cc = np.meshgrid(r, c)
    vals = ~np.isnan(array)
    return {"rr":rr, "cc":cc, "vals":vals}

def radial(data):
    import scipy.interpolate as interpolate
    hold = parseToM(data)
    rr, cc, vals = hold["rr"], hold["cc"], hold["vals"]    

    print("starting RBF interpolation")
    f = interpolate.Rbf(rr[vals], cc[vals], data[vals], function='linear')
    print("storing data")
    interpolated = f(rr, cc)
    return interpolated

def kriging(data):
    from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcess

    hold = parseToM(data)   
    rr, cc, vals = hold["rr"], hold["cc"], hold["vals"]

    print("starting gaussian process")
    gp = GaussianProcess(theta0=0.1, thetaL=.001, thetaU=1., nugget=0.1, storage_mode="light")
    print("fitting data")
    gp.fit(X=np.column_stack([rr[vals],cc[vals]]), y=data[vals])
    print("flattening data")
    rr_cc_as_cols = np.column_stack([rr.flatten(), cc.flatten()])
    print("reshaping data")
    a = 1000
    print(type(a))
    interpolated = gp.predict(rr_cc_as_cols, batch_size=a).reshape(data.shape)
    return interpolated

def prepareImage(filename, interpType="kriging"):
    print("opening image", filename)
    from PIL import Image
    f = Image.open(filename)
    image = f.load()
    image_size = f.size
    xmax = image_size[0]
    ymax = image_size[1]
    r = np.ndarray(shape=(xmax, ymax))
    g = np.ndarray(shape=(xmax, ymax))
    b = np.ndarray(shape=(xmax, ymax))
    print("processing image")
    for x in range(xmax):
        for y in range(ymax):
            value = image[x,y]
            if value[3] == 0:
                r[x,y], g[x,y], b[x,y] = [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]
            else:
                r[x,y], g[x,y], b[x,y] = value[:3]

    print("interpolating")
    if interpType == "kriging":
        rInterpInt = kriging(r).astype(int)
        gInterpInt = kriging(g).astype(int)
        bInterpInt = kriging(b).astype(int)
    elif interpType == "radial":
        rInterpInt = radial(r).astype(int)
        gInterpInt = radial(g).astype(int)
        bInterpInt = radial(b).astype(int)

    print("reapplying pixels")
    for i in range(rInterpInt.size):
        if rInterpInt.item(i) < 0:
            rInterpInt.itemset(i, 0)
        if gInterpInt.item(i) < 0:
            gInterpInt.itemset(i, 0)
        if bInterpInt.item(i) < 0:
            bInterpInt.itemset(i, 0)
        x = i%xmax
        y = int(np.floor(i/ymax))
        newValue = (rInterpInt[x,y], gInterpInt[x,y], bInterpInt[x,y], 255)
        image[x,y] = newValue
    print("saving")
    savename = "E:\\"+filename[3:9]+"."+interpType+".png"
    f.save(savename, "PNG")
    print("done")

for i in range(1,10):
    file = r"E:\occ"+str(i*100)+".png"
    prepareImage(file, interpType="kriging")
```

Comment: `n_eval / batch_size` should be using floor division if you are using python 3, but that seems to be in the library?

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a bug in scikit-learn in python 3 - the division [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/51a765a/sklearn/gaussian_process/gaussian_process.py#L510) results in a float in python 3, which `range` then rightly balks on.

There's a [corresponding issue here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/6483), but it seems to be a `wontfix`, citing that `GaussianProcess` is deprecated anyway

Comment: Thank you so much.  I will have to work to get the dev version installed then and rework my code to implement the new version.  I am using miniconda on a flash drive to run my program because I can't install anything at the school, so I will have to try to find a wheel and pip it in.

Comment: nevermind, I just found how to fix it in that thread and went into the code and corrected the error.